# InfinityFree redirection issue to index.html page from other pages

Tags: html, redirect

I just uploaded a simple 3-page website (Home/About/Contact) to *InfinityFree* via *FileZilla*, everything works fine, but the redirection from *About page* to *Home Page (index.html)* and *Contact Page* to *Home Page (index.html)* is not working. When I click *Home* link from the *About page* or from *Contact page* it redirected to [404 Error](https://infinityfree.net/errors/404/)

Please help me to overcome this redirection issue.

Comment: which service you use

Comment: FileZilla `Plain FTP Encription` and `Normal Logon`

Comment: use any frame work